# Assigning to typed variables across SWF boundaries breaks

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, document-class

I'm writing an application that uses extendable UI elements, whose precise implementation is determined at run-time using configuration. So for example, I want to show a list of items, which - depending on the configuration - may be shown as bulleted list, a numbered list, a two column list, etc. The containing application knows nothing about the specific implementation except that it is a type that supports the method call `setItems(items:Array):void`.

So I have set up a base class, for example:

```
package my.stuff {
    public class BaseList extends MovieClip {
        protected var m_items:Array;
        public function BaseList() {
            m_items = new Array();
        }
        public function setItems(items:Array):void {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                m_items.push(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have create a specialized implementation that does, for example, two column list:

```
package my.stuff {
    public class TwoColumnList extends BaseList {
        protected var m_columns:Array;
        public function TwoColumnList() {
            super();
            m_columns = new Array();
            m_columns.push(new Array());
            m_columns.push(new Array());
        }
        public override function setItems(items:Array):void {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                m_items.push(items[i]);
                m_columns[i%2].push(items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the UI itself is done in Flash Professional as an FLA with class TwoColumnList as the "document class". I compile the FLA ("publish") to the target SWF, then I try to load it into the application. Normally I'd expect this to work like so:

```
public function startLoading(implURL:String):void) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, doneLoadingImpl);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(implURL));
}

public function doneLoadingImpl(e:Event) {
    var info:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
    var impl:DisplayObject = info.content;
    m_containerClip.addChild(impl);
    var listImpl:BaseList = impl as BaseList;
    impl.setItems(m_allItems);
}
```

Except this doesn't work - the `addChild()` works fine but the cast to `BaseList` results in `null` (not an exception - just `null`). I can cast `impl` to `MovieClip` just fine, and I can also cast it directory to `TwoColumnList`, after which it casts-up nicely to `BaseList`, like this:

```
...
var listImpl:BaseList = impl as TwoColumnList;
...
```

So that works, but it really defeats the purpose of the whole exercise - which is to *not* know ahead of time the specific UI implementations that may be created in the future.

I read somewhere about doing `info.applicationDomain.getDefinition`, but I can't say it does any effect whatsoever.

I'm not an ActionScript developer in my day to day job, I've just been called to help out with some project whose main developer is no longer with the company, and I'm stumped - any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely related to the classes loading into different application domains. The type cast returns null, if the object is not a subclass of the class you are casting to - and it seems you have two versions of BaseList "competing" with each other.

If this is the case, you can work around it by explicitly loading the SWF into the same application domain as the main one:

```
 var ldrContext : LoaderContext = new LoaderContext ( false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain );
 var loader:Loader = new Loader();
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, doneLoadingImpl);
 loader.load(new URLRequest(implURL), ldrContext );
```

However, especially when loading external content, you should really be using interfaces.  Keeping the implementations decoupled is exactly what they were invented for. Check out [this blog page,](http://www.zedia.net/2008/another-good-use-of-interfaces/) it explains why you should use interfaces when loading external files (there also is a link to more fundamental info about interfaces), and incidentally, the author seems to have had a problem similar to yours... ;)

Comment: @weltraumpiray: Generally what you said sounds like a good idea, so I'll accept the answer, but it really wasn't the actual problem. The actual problem was that I'm dumb - The visual is created by compiling the FLA with the class I've built in FlashBuilder, but you have to set up the FLA to refer to the correct source dir, otherwise Flash Professional just ignores the fact that it doesn't see a class implementation of the specified "document class" and happily compiles a stub with no code. After I fixed the source dir setting in "ActionScript Settings", everything worked as I expected. :-)

Comment: @Guss: Thanks, it looks like your problem was indeed two different BaseLists competing ;)  You should think about the interfaces anyway - compiling the same class into more than one SWF is just not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @weltraumpirat, but in the specific case (not in the example code) the base class provides a lot of logic and the specialization is just used to "glue" the visual design in the FLA to the logic in the base class (and provide some specialization of metrics and some small behaviors).

Comment: Well, but the specialization requires the base class to be able to compile.  So it will be embedded in both files and bloat your byte code.